# Transformers for action recognition: Invalid argument: indices[0,1923] = -1 is not in [0, 12936)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to adapt a transformers code from https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/text/transformer.ipynb and use it in action recognition. My dataset is composed of 1000 actions with a variable length frame (N) where each frame contains 84 float32 points (x, y). I combine N and points to form a fairly big 1d tensor for every action. Actions have a variable max length of around 12K. My `batch = 1, num_layers = 2, d_model = 32, dff = 64, num_heads = 2`.

My error is:

```
2 root error(s) found.
(0) Invalid argument: indices[0,1923] = -1 is not in [0, 12936) [[node transformer_1/encoder_2/embedding_4/embedding_lookup (defined at :24) ]] (1) Invalid argument: indices[0,1923] = -1 is not in [0, 12936) [[node transformer_1/encoder_2/embedding_4/embedding_lookup (defined at :24) ]]
[[transformer_1/encoder_2/embedding_4/embedding_lookup/_24]] 0 successful operations. 0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_step_17044]

Function call stack: train_step -> train_step
```

if my tensor inputs are less than 3000 elements, I can run successfully run it but higher I get the above error. Has anyone run into this kinda of problem ? I have no idea what error means or how to fix it :(

Ps.: I read somewhere that this might be a TensorFlow bug (???) but not sure :/

any help again is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you input data. Embedding is usually the very first layer in transformer encoder. So probably the error is generated by the very first layer. One of you input indices is negative. Embedding layer expecting positive indices.